# vuejs ui is not updated after changing data in a @click method

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

I'm new to vue.js. I'm starting to migrate my angularjs app. I'm using vue cli to generate a new simple-webpack project. This creates a new webpack+vueLoader project. Everything went smoothly but now I have an issue. on my @click event I changed a portion of my Vue instance data but I can't see it reflected on UI.
I can see via Vue dev tools the instance is updated properly.

```
export default{
    data() {
      return {
         page: { items: null}
      }
    };

                        <div v-for="item in items" class="row-margin">
                            {{item.checked}}
                            <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.checked"><span>{{item.title}}</span>
                        </div>
```

and i update the items on my ajax success callback:

```
this.items = response.items;
```

I know vuejs implements its reactivity using getters and thus nothing else is needed. What's the missing part?

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving results from your ajax request? If so, are being listened in your div? If not, try changing:

`this.items = response.items;`

***TO***

`this.page.items = response.items`

In the code above your are updating a undeclared property inside vue vm

From Vue.js **#data** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

> The data object for the Vue instance. Vue will recursively convert its properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”. Once observed, you can no longer add reactive properties to the root data object. It is therefore recommended to declare all root-level reactive properties upfront, before creating the instance.

Cheers...

Comment: items is an array of object. i need vue to respond when a property in one of the array elements change.

Comment: What about [Computed Properties and Watchers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)?

Comment: computed cant be reactive right? it must execute the computation each time. If so I prefer avoiding it. Similar approach to watcher. Please see my answer, at the 'created' event, i do an ajax call. the response sets the vue instance data.items prop (created as null upon vue instance declaration). the the object in the data.items array dont have checked prop. when a user click something, it goes to the server, gets the checked items and using a loop sets true\false on data.items array object. If on the first response I add the checked prop all works well

Answer (score 0):

The item in items array doesnt have its checked property initially.
I add it dynamically when I set its value on the second ajax call.

items is fetched from the server. when I added the checked property when I initially set this prop from the first server response it worked perfectly.

is that the correct process??